# SystemJS doesn't load RxJS properly

Tags: javascript, systemjs, jspm

I'm having trouble getting RxJS to load properly using SystemJS (0.19.47)

Basically I have some TypeScript…

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from  "rxjs";

let subject = new BehaviorSubject(4);
```

That is transpired to JavaScript…

```
System.register(["rxjs"], function (exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var rxjs_1, subject;
    return {
        setters: [
            function (rxjs_1_1) {
                rxjs_1 = rxjs_1_1;
            }
        ],
        execute: function () {
            subject = new rxjs_1.BehaviorSubject(4);
        }
    };
});
```

However when it runs, rxjs_1_1 comes in looking something like the following, so when it tries to instantiate, rxjs_1.BehaviorSubject it is undefined, because it really should be calling rxjs_1.default.BehaviorSubject.

```
{
  "default": {
    "BehaviorSubject": function (_value) {…}
  }
}
```

All the other things I am loading with SystemJS seem to work fine, and because I can see BehaviorSubject under the "default" key, I know it is actually loading. I just don't understand why RxJS isn't working.

Comment: I'm not experiencing this problem with `0.19.47`, the issue only appears when i upgrade to `0.20.x` - for anyone who comes across this post, it's discussed here https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1675

Answer (score 1):

try `import {BehaviorSubject} from  "rxjs/Rx";`

Comment: Thanks, although that still doesn't seem to do it. It only changes to trying to call new Rx_1.BehaviorSubject(), when it only exists on Rx_1.default.BehaviorSubject()

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

The workaround was to change systemjs to one of the previous versions.
In my case 0.19.27 did work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from  "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";
```

or

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from "RxJs";
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is the same as above with it being under "default" and not at the root object where it is trying to access it off of. Although your 2nd suggestion `import { BehaviorSubject } from "RxJs";` fails because 'RxJs' isn't mapped to anything in SystemJS.

Comment: Further explanation on why this answer would work for the questioner would be helpful.  Changing import statements alone isn't a likely fix for this issue due to the nature of the question (he's receiving the module, but it doesn't appear correct).  In addition, the first import implies that `BehaviorSubject` is a named export but is requesting it from the named export file, which would fail as well in a well constructed module (e.g. `export default ...` in BehaviorSubject.js)

Answer (score 0):

You're importing RxJS correctly. For example:

```
// import.ts
import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs";

let subject = new BehaviorSubject(4);
console.log(subject);
```

When compiled to JS you can load it in `node` with (depending on your directory structure obviously):

```
const SystemJS = require('systemjs');

SystemJS.config({
  map: {
    'rxjs': './node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
  },
});

SystemJS.import('import_01.js');
```

So the question is why you think `BehaviorSubject` should be under some "default" property because RxJS package has no default export.

From the tags in your question it looks like you're using `jspm` but you didn't mention it in you post so the problem is probably there and not in SystemJS.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem. The code below not working because Observable is **undefined**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
let obs = Observable.create((observer) => observer.next(1));
```

But when I change code in JS file like this

```
obs = Observable_1.default.Observable.create(...)
```

then all works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try my settings:

**tsconfig.json**

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    ...
}
```

`"module": "system"` is not working well in my experience.

**ts**

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
```